Is `useImperativeHandle` really needed?
I was wondering if useImperativeHandle really needed, since I can return the methods I want, with something like a factory function.
For Example, I did this
export function Modal() {
    const d = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);

    return {
        open() {
            console.log("open called");
            d.current?.showModal()
        },
        Element({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
            return createPortal(
                <dialog ref={d}> {children} </dialog>,
                document.getElementById("modal")!
            );
        }
    }
}

instead of using useImperativeHandle hook to share an API. and the usage can be like this
export function App(){
    const modal = Modal()
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={modal.open}>click</button>
            <modal.Element>
                <p>this is a test</p>
            </modal.Element>
        </div>
    )
}

however, I do not know if there is any optimization related functionality provided with useImperativeHandle hook... and I'm not sure if my way will because any unwanted behavior in big scale

In your example, Modal isn't a component or hook, so it shouldn't be calling useRef. (See Rules of Hooks.)

@ruakh It actually is a hook now. It should be called useModal though

@Bergi: I guess you must define "hook" a bit differently from me. As far as I'm concerned, hook names always start with use. [doc link]

@ruakh That's just a (very useful and much needed) naming convention. It's not required by React for hooks to work. A custom hook is just a function calling other hooks.

@ruakh let say I fix the name to be useModal and lets make it a custom hook, does this mean useImperativeHandle is not really needed to share an API (which is the question)

@sultanmotiri: So, I think that your implementation has some problems; for example, I think you'll see excessive re-renders resulting from the fact that modal.Element is a different component function on each render. But I think that with some effort you could probably fix those issues. Broadly speaking, most APIs are not "really needed"; they're there to help you write good code well, but you can usually find other ways to accomplish more-or-less the same thing. That's probably a good learning exercise, but probably not something you'd want to do in "real" code.
